# How to implement a custom AdapterFactory for Sling Resource?

Tags: java, apache, osgi, sling, aem

The Adobe AEM software provides several classes which can take an apache Sling Resource and adapt it to another class like so:

```
Page page = resource.adaptTo(Page.class);
```

To use this syntax with classes that you author and control this boils down to simply implementing the [Adaptable](https://sling.apache.org/documentation/the-sling-engine/adapters.html) interface.

However, if you want to enable a Resource to adaptTo your new custom class, is seems that you have to implement the AdapterFactory interface and register it in OSGI.

This is how the [Adobe website](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/5-3/developing/sling-adapters.html#How%20it%20works) describes it:

> By an **AdapterFactory**, which can map arbitrary objects.
>   The objects must still implement the Adaptable interface and must extend SlingAdaptable (which passes the adaptTo call to a central adapter manager).
>   **This allows hooks into the adaptTo mechanism for existing classes, such as Resource**.

I have walked through the SlingScriptAdapterFactory code, but ultimately I am not connecting the dots here.  Basically I want to do this:

```
MyClass myClass = Resource.adaptTo(MyClass.class);
```

Do I create a class that implements AdapterFactory and simply deploy it with the package expecting that Sling will just find it by type or is there more to it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a little bit better documentation https://sling.apache.org/documentation/the-sling-engine/adapters.html

So you should implement the Adaptable interface, as you already described. Then create a properly annotated AdapterFactory:

```
@Component
@Service(value=org.apache.sling.api.adapter.AdapterFactory.class)
@Properties({
   @Property(name = "adaptables", value = { "org.apache.sling.api.resource.Resource" }),
   @Property(name = "adapters", value = { "org.sling.MyClass" })
})
public class MyAdapterFactory implements AdapterFactory{
    public  <AdapterType> AdapterType getAdapter(final Object adaptable, Class<AdapterType> type){
          return new MyClassAdapter(adaptable);   
    }     
}
```

Comment: I was able to verify this and it was just what I needed.  I hadn't understood that the comments on the Apache site outlined the necessary SCR annotations to register my adapter [https://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-maven-scr-plugin/scr-annotations.html] Now I just need to figure out how to express the adapters annotation property as a collection of classes that the adapter supports. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Note that I've been working on a simpler way to create Sling adapters, by annotating methods with a new @Adapter annotation, as in

```
  @Component
  @Service
  public class C implements AdapterMethodsProvider {
    @Adapter
    public CustomerRecord convert(Resource r) { ... }

    @Adapter
    public Person adaptToPerson(Resource r) { ... }
  }
```

See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SLING-2938 for details, but note that this is not even in the Sling trunk yet, so it will take some time before it's released and available in AEM/CQ.

Comment: This would be convenient. I will take a look.  It seems in harmony with the work that is part of Slice [http://www.cognifide.com/blogs/cq/make-your-cq-life-easier-with-slice/] which aims to use annotations to map POJO properties to Jcr properties.